# Numerical instability in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision

For the following summing operation in Python 3.6.0:

```
6.89 + .1
```

I got the result `6.9899999999` This causes a bug in my code. How to fix this, such that the results be similar to 6.99? Please note I can't handle this by trying to approximate the result using my own code. Since I'm working on time series processing, it would create other problems. In other words, I'm looking for a solution using "the language settings".

Comment: Perhaps look into the [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/decimal.html) library.

Comment: And read the floating point section of the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).